# Get the author name of current author archive

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get the author name of current author archive:

```
if (is_author()) return AUTHOR_NAME;
```

But how can I get current author name?

Comment: did you try get_user_by()? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by

Comment: i need to get author name outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually an interesting trick to this one.
In an author archive, the one thing you know about all the posts in the query is that they are all by the author you want. In any case, the function you will want is [get_the_author()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author).

If you want the author name after you have already entered (and even exited) the loop, the last post that was loaded will be by the author, and using [get_the_author()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author) will be enough.

If, on the other hand, you want the author's name before you have entered the loop, you need to load the first post's data, and then rewind the query before the loop is entered as so:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    $author = get_the_author();
    rewind_posts();
}
```

If you don't need the loop at all, you can skip the rewinding.

If there are no posts in the query, you will have a slightly tougher job.

Answer (score 2):

```
global $wp_query;
$author = get_user_by('slug', $wp_query->query_vars['author_name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
the_post();
$author_name = get_the_author();
rewind_posts();
```

Answer (score 1):

No `rewind_posts()` tricks needed:

```
$qo = get_queried_object();
$author = $qo->data->display_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will display the author of the current page/post:

```
<?php echo get_the_author() ; ?>
```